# Openmp nested for loop with ordered output

Tags: c++, for-loop, output, openmp

I'm currently trying to find a fast and reliable way to parallelize a set of loops with if conditions where I need to save a result in the inner loop.
The code is supposed to go through a huge amount of points in a 3D grid. For some points within this volume I have to check another condition (checking for an angle) and if this condition fulfilled I have to calculate a density.

The fastest ways so far were  `#pragma omp parallel for private (x,y,z) collapse(3)` outside of all for loops or `#pragma omp parallel for` for the inner most loop (phiInd) which is not only the largest loop but also calls a CPU-intensive function.

I need to store the density value in the densityarr within the inner loop. The densityarray is then later saved seperately. 
My problem now is, that depending on the number of threads I set, I get different results in ,y density array. The serial version and an openmp run with just 1 thread have identical results.
Increasing the number of threads leads to results at the same points, but those results are different from the serial version.

I know there is `#pragma omp for ordered` but this results in a too slow calculation. 
Is there a way to parallelize this loop while still getting my results ordered according to my points (x,y,z)?
Or maybe clearer: Why does increasing the thread number change my result?

```
double phipoint, Rpoint, zpoint;
double phiplane;
double distphi = 2.0 * M_PI / nPlanes; //set desired distace to phi to assign point to fluxtubeplane
double* densityarr = new double[max_x_steps * max_y_steps * max_z_steps];


for (z = 0; z < max_z_steps; z++) {
    for (x = 0; x < max_x_steps; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < max_y_steps; y++) {
            double x_center = x * stepSizeGrid - max_x / 2;
            double y_center = y * stepSizeGrid - max_y / 2;
            double z_center = z * stepSizeGrid - max_z / 2;
            cartesianCoordinate* pos = new cartesianCoordinate(x_center, y_center, z_center);
            linearToroidalCoordinate* tor = linearToroidal(*pos);
            simpleToroidalCoordinate* stc = simpleToroidal(*pos);

            phipoint = tor->phi;
            if (stc->r <= 0.174/*0.175*/) {//check if point is in vessel

                for (int phiInd = 0; phiInd < nPlanes; ++phiInd) {
                    phiplane = phis[phiInd];

                    if (abs(phipoint - phiplane) <= distphi) {//find right plane for point
                        Rpoint = tor->R;
                        zpoint = tor->z;                
                        densityarr[z * max_y_steps * max_x_steps + x * max_y_steps + y] = TubePlanes[phiInd].getMinDistDensity(Rpoint, zpoint);

                    }
                }
            }

            delete pos, tor, stc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `phipoint` / `phiplane` defined. What type has `densityarr`?

Comment: Before those loops. `phipoint` and `phiplane` are both double. `densityarr` is double*..

`double phiplane, phipoint;
double* densityarr = new double[max_x_steps * max_y_steps * max_z_steps];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to address the errors in your parallel versions. You race-conditions writing to the shared variables `phipoint` (parallel outer loops) and `phiplane`,`Rpoint`,`zpoint` (any loops parallel). You must declare those private, or better yet, declare them locally in the first place (which makes them implicitly private). That way the code is much easier to reason about - which is very important for parallel codes.

Parallelizing the outer loops like you describe is the obvious and very likely most efficient approach. If there are severe load imbalances (`stc->r <= 0.174` not being evenly distributed among the points), you might want to use `schedule(dynamic)`.

Parallelizing the inner loop seems unnecessary in your case. Generally outer loops provide better efficiency because of less overhead - unless they don't expose enough parallel work, have some race conditions, have dependencies, or cache issues. It would however be a worthwhile exercise to try and measure it. However, there may be a race condition upon writing to `densityarr`, if more than one of the phis satisfy the condition. Overall that loop seems a bit odd - since you only use at most one of the results in `densityarr`, you could rather reverse the loop and cancel once you found the first one. That helps serial execution a lot, but may inhibit parallelization. Also, if you don't find a phi that satisfies the condition - or if the point is not in the vessel, then the respective entry in `densityarr` remains uninitialized - that can be very dangerous because you cannot later determine if the value is valid or not.

A general remark, don't allocate objects with `new` unless you need to. Just put `pos` on the stack, likely gives you better performance. It can be a performance issue to allocate memory within a (parallel) loop, so you might want to rethink the way you get your `Toroidal`s.

Note that I do assume that `TubePlanes[phiInd].getMinDistDensity` has no side effects, otherwise parallelization would be problematic.

Comment: You saved my week! Thank you! I declared my variables locally and initialized densityarr with zeros. My Upvotes doesn't count yet, but your answer solved my issue.

Comment: @LeBo Glad to help! Please mark the question as solved by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer.